Binding IP address to Docker Container produces error - starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 10.0.0.4:9200: bind: cannot assign requested address
Situation: there are two VMs in the private network:

Linux web server with the private IP 10.0.0.4
Linux server with ElasticSearch Docker container

I want to restrict connections to ElasticSearch to only from the Web Server (10.0.0.4) and the ElasticSearch VM itself (localhost)
The following docker run command produces an error:
docker run -d --restart always \
  --name elasticsearch \
  -p 10.0.0.4:9200:9200 \
  -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 \
  elasticsearch:7.17.20

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint elasticsearch (7de85c6ef6614f0d0a9804250911dde2e73172a64ede3d36b7b6c758c78f7231): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 10.0.0.4:9200: bind: cannot assign requested address.

If I only have "-p 0.0.0.0 9200:9200" binding rule, I can connect from both resources, but I wanted to be more strict here of who can connect to ElasticSearch (have more VMs in the network), and since UFW can't be used with Docker in this case, I thought the IP binding would work. Leaving "-p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200" allow connections from localhost only.
I'm aware I can use Cloud firewall, and I do that, but Cloud Firewalls don't always apply to private networks - depends on the provider.
I might be misunderstanding IP binding feature, or using it incorrectly. Please advise.

That -p option says that your host has the IP address 10.0.0.4 and it should accept connections to that address.  It sounds like that's the IP address of the client, not an address the current machine has.

@DavidMaze that's correct - 10.0.0.4 is IP of the client machine within the same network. If "-p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200" allows connections only from the host machine, and "-p 0.0.0.0:9200:9200" allows connections from everywhere, I expected it to work with the client's IP address. I guess I misunderstood this Docker feature.

Say your host is on two networks.  192.168.0.1 is its external address, and 10.20.30.40 is its internal address.  You can use one of those host addresses as the IP argument to -p to make it listen on only one interface or the other.  It does not provide IP ACLing, which seems to be what you're asking for.
